# joining a twitch IRC channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, irc, twitch

My function which should join a channel doesn't get any response from the server.
The weird thing that when I join a server I do get a response.
but somehow, when I try to join a channel I don't receive any return.

```
    private void join()
    {
        connection.Writer.Write("JOIN #" + ChannelName.Trim().ToLower() + "\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("JOIN #" + ChannelName.Trim().ToLower() + "\r\n");
        connection.Writer.Flush();

        //debug code
        while (true)
        {
            while (connection.reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                String line = connection.reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains("PING :"))
                {
                    connection.Writer.Write("PONG :" + line.Substring(line.IndexOf("PING :") + 6) + "\r\n");
                    connection.Writer.Flush();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:

It seems that twitch doesn't do

```
"PING :"
```

but instead does

```
"PING "
```

weirdly changing only this doesn't  seem to be fixing it.
This is one of the moments where I would say. "My code is working and I don't know why."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [API](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/en/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc). It seems so, that it's not so easy to get an valid login. U have to trigger the API at some points.

Regards, k1ll3r8e

Comment: I've found that one already, but since the documentation isn't  that great. Anyways, I've fixed it and I'll edit my own post with answers for the future.

Comment: Have you also found this [article](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md)? This looks really promising for me.

Comment: That article actually solved it for me earlyer on the day. Thank you anyways.